# A limit technique in shifting the mean of normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

This question arises from showing the existence of some strange admissible estimators in the theory of point estimate in statistics.

Let $\varphi(x)=\exp(-{1\over 2}x^2)$, then show for any non-negative measurable $r(\cdot)$ with $\{r=0\}$ of zero Lebesgue measure  that
$$\frac{\int_0^\infty r(x)\varphi(x-\theta)\ dx}{\int_{-\infty}^0 \varphi(x-\theta)\ dx}\to \infty$$
as $\theta \to +\infty$.

The conclusion shall be obvious for constant $r(\cdot)$, while if we let $r(x)=\exp(-{1\over 2}x^2)$, we get the limit $0/0$-type, and is hard to expect showing one is bounded from below and one tends to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the positivity of the integrand, we have

$$\begin{align*} \int_{(0,\infty)} \varphi(x-\theta) \cdot r(x) \, dx &\geq \int_{(0,\theta)} \varphi(x-\theta) \cdot r(x) \, dx \\ &\geq \inf_{x \in [0,\theta]} \varphi(x-\theta) \cdot \int_{(0,\theta)} r(x) \, dx \\ &= \exp \left( - \frac{\theta^2}{2} \right) \cdot \int_{(0,\theta)} r(x) \, dx \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

for any $\theta \geq 0$. On the other hand,

$$\begin{align*} \int_{(-\infty,0)} \varphi(x-\theta) \, dx &= \int_{(\theta,\infty)} \varphi(x) \, dx \\ &\leq \int_{(\theta,\infty)} \frac{x}{\theta} \cdot \varphi(x) \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot \exp \left( -\frac{\theta^2}{2} \right) \tag{2} \end{align*}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we conclude

$$\frac{\int_{(0,\infty)} \varphi(x-\theta) \cdot r(x) \, dx}{\int_{(-\infty,0)} \varphi(x-\theta) \, dx} \geq \theta \cdot \int_{(0,\theta)} r(x) \, dx \stackrel{\theta \to \infty}{\to} \infty$$